# VSCode: Django Template and url() background-image parsing

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, django-templates

I am writing something in django in vscode and there is a line like this:

`<header class="min-h-screen w-full bg-black bg-opacity-75 showcase border-gray-600 border-b-8 flex justify-center py-20 bg-no-repeat"  style="background-image: url('{% static 'myimage.jpg' %}');">`

It keeps giving me 3 problem in the problem tab. It is underlining red `myimage.` . The problems are:

`) expected css(css-rparentexpected)[9,181]`

`semicolon expected (css-semicolonexpected)[9,199]`

`at-rule or selector expected css(css-ruleorselectorexpected)[9,210]`

After tweaking a little bit I suspect the problem is with nested quotations. Although code is running fine and I can see `myimage.jpg` in the localhost.

How to remove the 3 problems without changing anything in the script? I tried to push the cross button in the left of every problem but that doesn't work. My tabs, working directories in left, everything is red because of this. It's bugging me horribly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `'` string inside a `'` string, the parser ends the `url` string at the first quote of `'myimage.jpg'`

You can solve it in 2 ways

```
{% static "myimage.jpg" as myimage %}
<header class="min-h-screen w-full bg-black bg-opacity-75
showcase border-gray-600 border-b-8 flex justify-center
py-20 bg-no-repeat"
style="background-image: url('{{ myimage }}');">
```

Or

```
<header class="min-h-screen w-full bg-black bg-opacity-75
showcase border-gray-600 border-b-8 flex justify-center
py-20 bg-no-repeat"
style="background-image: url('{% get_static_prefix %}myimage.jpg');">
```

Comment: It is not working. without ` 'myimage.jpg' ` it is not showing the picture in the webpage. The picture is shown either with ` 'myimage.jpg' ` or ` "myimage.jpg" ` . But in both cases vscode is giving problems.

Comment: can it be any bug?

Comment: @mirabirhossain See my edit